# custom element: not able to extend HTMLProgressElement

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

I want to create a custom progress bar and extend from the native html progress bar. However, the `console.log` does not get called when I try to extend from the `HTMLProgressElement`

```html
<free-shipping-bar value="32" max="100"></free-shipping-bar>
```

```js
class FreeShippingBar extends HTMLProgressElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('test')
    }
}

if (!customElements.get('free-shipping-bar'))
    customElements.define('free-shipping-bar', FreeShippingBar, { extends: 'progress' });
```

When I change it to `class FreeShippingBar extends HTMLElement { ... }` the `console.log` is called.

Why is that? I would like to extend the native progress element.

Comment: Using Safari? Apple has, since 2015 or sometime and with valid arguments, stated they will never implement _Customized Built-In Elements_

Answer (score 0):

While the comment about Safari is right you misunderstood the use of built-ins.

Try replacing your HTML with the following:

```html
<progress value="32" max="100" is="free-shipping-bar"></progress>
```

What it says is that you are using progress element that behaves like `free-shipping-bar`. It then prints the "test" log message and renders the element.